# Simple conditional probability question

Tags: probability

Harvey is often late for work. He leaves home late 60% of the time, but then drives very fast. This gives him a 50% chance of getting to work on time. When Harvey leaves home on time, he drives so slowly that he is late 70% of the time. What is the probability that Harvey left home on time if he gets to work on time?

I used a tree diagram and found the answer .12. However, I am not sure of this is correct, and if it is, why it is correct. Could someone give me some intuition on what's going on in this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote event "leave home late" as $A$, event "work on time" as $B$. Then
$$
\Pr(B | A) = 0.5 \\
\Pr(B | \neg A) = 1 - 0.7 \\
\Pr(A) = 0.6
$$

To compute $\Pr(\neg A | B)$, i.e., the probability that Harvey left home on time **IF** he gets to work on time, use
$$
\Pr(\neg A | B) = \frac{\Pr(\neg A, B)}{\Pr(B)}
$$
and to compute $\Pr(\neg A, B)$ and $\Pr(B)$, use
$$
\Pr(\neg A,  B) = \Pr(B | \neg A) \cdot \Pr(\neg A)
$$
and
$$
\Pr(B) = \Pr(\neg A, B) + \Pr(A, B)
$$

Your answer $0.12$ is **NOT** correct, it's in fact the prability $\Pr(\neg A, B)$, i.e, the probability that Harvey left home on time **AND** work on time. A simple calculation shows that
$$
\Pr(\neg A, B) = 0.3 * 0.4 = 0.12
$$
and
$$
\Pr(B) = 0.42
$$
thus
$$
\Pr(\neg A | B) = \frac{0.12}{0.42} = \frac{2}{7}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at this:  Imagine this occurring 1000 times.  60% of the time, 600 days, he starts late.  Of those 600 days, he is on time 50% of the time or 300 days.  The other 300 days, he is late.

He starts on time the other 400 days.  Of those 400 days, he is late 70% of the time- .7(400)= 280 days, he is on time the other 400- 280= 120 days.

So he is on time a total 300+ 120= 420 days and started on time 300 of those.  the probability that he started on time given that he arrived at work on time is 300/420= 5/7= 7.